# Как получить состояние балуна у метки?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Может кто-то подсказать как получить состояние баллуна (открыт он или закрыт)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод isOpen(). Документация лежит тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Balloon-docpage/

Comment: Проверял это, он выдал null при mouseenter, поэтому думал не подойдет, не там проверку устраивал
Спасибо